# IRC Send Queue (X messages in Y seconds)

Tags: java, irc

I have a tendency to over-think things, but couldn't find anything about this anywhere. Most IRC networks/channels with a send limit implements it in a way where you can only send X messages over a certain period of time (in the case of out network, 5 in 5s), meaning that I either have to have a long delay between messages, or implement a way to make sure I don't send more than that while still sending messages quickly up to that point. How would I go about doing the latter?

(I'm doing this in Java, but the question obviously does not rely on this, so any code referenced in answers can be of any language.)

Answer (score 1):

Queue all outgoing messages. Only send them while you are under the limit. If you are above the limit, add them to your queue and send them once enough time has passed so that you are under the limit again.

You'd only have to figure out a way to detect those limits or hard-code them if you are only using the same network where you know them.

Comment: The problem I'm having is knowing when I'm under the limit. My current queue system is having a 1000ms delay between all messages in the queue, which isn't ideal in situations where I simply want to send, say, 2 messages.

Comment: You have to track the timestamp when you send the last messages. Then you can simply look up if you have already sent more then 5 messages in the last 5 seconds, or not. If you are over the limit, add the messages to a queue, else send them.